# Shell prompt on the same line as stdout

Tags: shell

I am facing a strange issue, in a shell script. The output of the cat command ends on the same line as bash shell prompt.

below command is giving the output as '3', but it should actually be '4'.

```
 cat mpgwstatus|grep B2B|wc -l
```

"mpgwstatus" file has below content

```
  <ServiceName>B2B-UID-MPG</ServiceName></ServicesStatus><ServicesStatus xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <ServiceName>B2B-Cert-MPG</ServiceName></ServicesStatus><ServicesStatus xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <ServiceName>B2B-UID-NonXML_MPG</ServiceName></ServicesStatus><ServicesStatus xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <ServiceName>B2B-Cert-NonXML_MPG</ServiceName></ServicesStatus></dp:status></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope      >
```

I have tried below, but still I am not able to get the actual output (4).

```
 cat mpgwstatus;echo|grep B2B|wc -l
```

What is the problem with the command that I am using?

Comment: You must have some strange characters, like `\r`. Try doing `cat -vte` or also `dos2unix` if the file comes from a DOS environment.

Comment: I have tried `cat -vte` , but still the same issue.

Comment: I tried it on my Linux machine and it returned 4. Why are you using `cat`? Just do `grep B2B mpgwstatus | wc -l`

Comment: I have tried `grep B2B mpgwstatus | wc -l` , same issue persists.